# Mask an url in Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'd like to convert an url with the format

http:// foo.example.com:81/foo/s?id=(a number)

into something like

http:// www.example.com/foo/(a number)/

in Nginx.

I've tried with proxy_pass and rewrite but it doesn't work. I believe this is fairly simple but I'm not familiar with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, finally I've figured it out.

```
location /foo {
    rewrite ^/foo/(.*)/ /foo/s?id=$1 break;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
}
```

I set proxy_buffering to off because it was a comet application.

Answer (score -1):

```
- rewrite ^/foo/(.*)/ /foo/s?id=$1 break;
+ rewrite ^/foo/(.*)/ /foo/$1 break;
```